# Autocomplete is not working in Express.js code

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, express, npm

[code for autocomplete in jquery](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rQPe6.png)

[code for getting data in express js][2\

[code for fetching the data in express js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rVMev.png)

Comment: Can you copy your code and (EDIT) paste it in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your code as follows:

```
$(".autocomplete").autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/get_vehicle",
            method: "get",
            data: {
                term: request.term
            },
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.length) {
                    response($.map(data, function (item) {
                        return {
                            label: item.model,
                            value: item.model
                        };
                    }));
                }
            }
        });
    },
});
```

And

```
router.get('/get_vehicle', function (req, res) {
  vehicle.find(function (err, result) {
    res.status(200).send(result);
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

you are missing a '/'

change 'get_vehicle' to '/get_vehicle' in index.js